# Separate positive and negative occurrences of PHOAS variables in presence of recursive binders

Tags: haskell, graph, abstract-syntax-tree, dsl

### Structured Graph encoding in Parametric Higher Order Abstract Syntax (PHOAS)

I'm reading the paper
"Functional Programming with Structured Graphs" by Olivera and Cook
([Slides](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Ebmv/Away_Day/fplad12-talk_henrik.pdf),
[draft paper](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Ewcook/Drafts/2012/graphs.pdf).)
proposing an elegant solution to encode sharing and cycles in graph-like structures using recursive bindings in PHOAS.

#### The AST (stream example)

For example, streams with back edges can be encoded as :

```
-- 'x' is the element type, 'b' is the PHOAS's abstract variable:
data PS0 x b = Var0 b
             | Mu0 (b -> PS0 x b) -- recursive binder
             | Cons0 x  (PS0 x b)
-- Closed terms:
newtype Stream0 x = Stream0 { runS0 :: forall b. PS0 x b }

-- Example : [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...
exPS0 = Stream0 $ Cons0 0 (Mu0 $ \x -> Cons0 1 (Cons0 2 $ Var0 x))
```

#### Folding (to list)

The AST can be folded into list without taking account of the cycles:

```
toListPS0 :: Stream0 x -> [x]
toListPS0 = go . runS0
  where
    go (Var0 x) = x
    go (Mu0 h) = go . h $ [] -- nil
    go (Cons0 x xs) =  x : go xs

-- toListPS0 exPS0 == [0, 1, 2]
```

Or produce an infinite list, by taking the fix-point of recursive binders:

```
toListRecPS0 :: Stream0 x -> [x]
toListRecPS0 = go . runS0
  where
    go (Var0 x) = x
    go (Mu0 h) = fix $ go . h -- fixpoint
    go (Cons0 x xs) = x : go xs

-- toListRecPS0 exPS0 == [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...
```

#### Quasi-monadic `join`

The authors note that the encoding is a quasi-monad, having both `join` and `return`, but not `fmap`.

```
returnPS0 :: b -> PS0 x b
returnPS0 = Var0

joinPS0 :: PS0 x (PS0 x b) -> PS0 x b
joinPS0 (Var0 b) = b
joinPS0 (Mu0 h) = Mu0 $ joinPS0 . h . Var0
joinPS0 (Cons0 x xs) = Cons0 x $ joinPS0 xs
```

This can be used to unroll one level of recursive binding:

```
unrollPS0 :: Stream0 x -> Stream0 x
unrollPS0 s = Stream0 $ joinPS0 . go $ runS0 s
  where
    go (Mu0 g) = g . joinPS0 . Mu0 $ g
    go (Cons0 x xs) = Cons0 x $ go xs
    go e = e

-- toListPS0 . unrollPS0 $ exPS0 == [0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

### PHOAS For Free

This reminded me the excellent article by Edward Kmett on FPComplete:
[PHOAS For Free](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/phoas).
The idea is to make the AST a profunctor, separating negative and positive occurrence of PHOAS's variable.

The "fixpoint with place-order" of a functor is represented with a free-monad-like AST
([Fegaras and Sheard](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.36.2763)):

```
data Rec p a b = Place b
               | Roll (p a (Rec p a b))
```

Provided that `p` is a profunctor (or that `p a` is a functor), `Rec p a` is a monad (and a functor !).

The stream AST can be encoded with the non-recursive functor `PSF` :

```
data PSF x a b = MuF (a -> b)
               | ConsF x   b

-- Type and pattern synonyms:
type PS1 x = Rec (PSF x)
pattern Var1 x = Place x
pattern Mu1 h = Roll (MuF h)
pattern Cons1 x xs = Roll (ConsF x xs)

-- Closed terms:
newtype Stream1 x = Stream1 { runS1 :: forall b. PS1 x b b }

-- Example : [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...
exPS1 = Stream1 $ Cons1 0 (Mu1 $ \x -> Cons1 1 (Cons1 2 (Var1 x)))
```

### The problem

The `join` from the `Rec` monad instance is different than the original `joinPS1` from the paper !

A literate translation of `joinPS0` using the pattern synonyms is:

```
joinPS1 :: PS1 x (PS1 x b b) (PS1 x b b) -> PS1 x b b
joinPS1 (Var1 b) = b
joinPS1 (Mu1 h) = Mu1 $ joinPS1 . h . Var1 -- Var1 affects the negative occurrences
joinPS1 (Cons1 x xs) = Cons1 x $ joinPS1 xs
```

Whereas, inlining `(>>=)` and `fmap` in `(>>= id)` give us :

```
joinFreePSF :: PS1 x a (PS1 x a b) -> PS1 x a b
joinFreePSF (Var1 b) = b
joinFreePSF (Mu1 h) = Mu1 $ joinFreePSF . h -- No Var1 !
joinFreePSF (Cons1 x xs) = Cons1 x $ joinFreePSF xs
```

So my question is, **why this difference?**

The problem is that operations like `unrollPS1` requires a `join` that "smash" both the positive and negative occurrences of the monad (like in the `joinPS1` type).

I think it's related to the recursive nature of the binders. I tried to rewrite `unrollPS1` by working with the types, but I'm not sure to have a full understanding of what is going on at the value level.

#### Remark

A fully general type of `joinPS1` (inferred by the compiler) is

```
joinPS1 :: PS1 x (PS1 x' a a') (PS1 x a' b) -> PS1 x a' b
```

It can be specialized with `a' ~ a ~ b` and `x' ~ x`.

#### PS:

I don't try to achieve anything specific, it's more a matter of curiosity, like trying to connect the dots.

The full code with all the instances is
[available here (gist)](https://gist.github.com/Piezoid/8e203f71adb3f767d67e).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually easily reconstruct the Olivera and Cook `join` from my "profunctor HOAS" free monad join:

```
joinPS1 = join . lmap Var
```

Their version does the only thing it *can* do in their type.

There they have to keep the `a = b`, so it does so by introducing a `Var`. Here we can just put it on separately. It isn't required for the monad, and shouldn't be done for all cases.

The *need* to keep `a` and `b` in sync is why theirs can only be a "pseudo-monad" and why profunctor HOAS lets you actually have a real monad.